# Finding a document in mongoose and fetching a specific part

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'll start by describing what I'm trying to achieve. I'm currently working on a discord bot for my Destiny 2 Clan, one of the commands I'm trying to implement is a joinid command, where you would use the command and @ a user, and it will return the users steamID. Unfortunately, the discord bot does not have access to the connections of a discord user. The solution I came up was to make an Oauth2 login for the members of the clan, when they log in they authorize an app to get the connection information from the discord API which is then saved in a database. The Oauth2 app is finished and working, the issues are with the bot fetching the data from the database. So far I've only tried  `Model.find` when I tried yesterday it returned an insane amount of information alot more than the actual document contained, however today it only returns [object Object], so I must've messed up the code.
Probably worth mentioning that this is my first JavaScript project.

Here's the Schema for the MongoDB documents:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    discordId: {type: String, required: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    connection: {type: Array, required: true}

});


const DiscordUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I attached an images of how the documents look in the database

And this is the code for the command I have so far:

```
if (cmd.includes("joinid")) {
        playerid = cmd.slice(10, -1);
        const steamidentifier = DiscordUser.find({ discordId: playerid});
        console.log(`${steamidentifier}`);
        
    }
```

By looking at the image you can see that there are separate objects for each connection (i.e. Spotify, battle.net, steam, twitch, etc. etc.) But as far as I'm aware the steamID is the only ID with 17 digits only consisting of numbers, so that's what I planned to use to identify the steamID.
So what I'm asking is if there is a way to, first of all, fetch the actual document from the database by using the discordId, and then if there is a way to select the actual steamID from the array easily.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmeN3.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you're looking for 1 document then I suggest you use `findOne()` instead.

Second of all, you need to use the `callback` function to get the results of your query.

```js
if (cmd.includes("joinid")) {
    playerid = cmd.slice(10, -1);
    const steamidentifier = DiscordUser.findOne({
        discordId: playerid
    }, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res.connection.find(con => con.type === 'steam').id)
    });
}
```